# IE7 left:%; bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a project, I use the latest [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), and I bumped into a IE7 specific alignment bug. [view this](http://timo.geekcavecreations.com/ie7bug/leftbug.html) in IE7 and then in any other browser, for example Firefox, IE8 and even IE6. Notice how the little "|" between the lower links is not visible in IE7, yet it looks fine in the other browsers. Removing the left:-100%; from on line 61 fixes the bug [as seen here](http://timo.geekcavecreations.com/ie7bug/leftbug2.html), but i need this "left" for positioning.

Any help on what is causing this bug, or potential ideas on how to fix it much needed.

Comment: Could you explain what you want? It is not very clear what you want to achieve, but your approach seems strange.

Comment: I'm trying to make IE7 behave like the other browsers, just view this http://timo.geekcavecreations.com/ie7bug/leftbug.html in IE7 then in any other browser and try to spot the difference. (its the | between the links), as you can see the bottom ones are fine, while the top one is driving me mad... if im still unclear then please tell me so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you use the left:-100% trick but what you do can be achieved much more easily. You want to make the toplevel ul to be inline-block, Make "Forums" be block level and the other ul block level (and the li items in there be inline) then you can forego many of the big positioning commands, and don't do ill-defined things like left:-100%

Comment: just try #nav ul {display:block;} and you will see how everything breaks.

Comment: I am asking why IE7 is behaving differently, not what positioning i should use.